# plot graph in device

Tags: r, graphics, pipe

I have the following situation: I use an external command ([plantuml](http://plantuml.com)) to create a graph. This is done via R by using [a (my) package](https://github.com/rkrug/plantuml). The resulting graph can be a file (`png`, `svg`, `eps`, `pdf`, `vdx` or `LaTeX/Tikz` with or without preamble) or I can send the image to `stdout`, using the same formats.

Now I want to plot this graph as R-like as possible, i.e. in a graphic device. At the moment I am using a temporary file, which I display using `readPNG()` and `grid::grid.raster()` which works, but I am not that happy with this approach as

1. I have to use a temporary file which I would like to avoid, and
2. it is a raster format and I would prefer a vector format.

My question is therefore:

1. Is there a way to display any of the vector formats in a graphics device in R?
2. Can I pipe stdout (the result from the call to `plantuml`) directly into the device without having to create an intermediate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use either [grImport](https://cran.r-project.org/package=grImport) or [grImport2](https://cran.r-project.org/package=grImport2). The former supports PostScript while the latter supports SVG. Note that in general post-processing of the SVG image will be necessary:

```
library(magrittr)
infile <- tempfile()
svglite::svglite(infile, width = 10, height = 7)
ggplot2::qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = factor(cyl))
dev.off()

system(paste("cat", infile), intern = TRUE) %>%
  paste0(., collapse = "") %>%
  charToRaw(.) %>%
  rsvg::rsvg_svg(NULL, file = NULL) %>%
  rawToChar(.) %>%
  grImport2::readPicture(.) %>%
  grImport2::grid.picture(.)
```

The example above uses an artificial `cat` to generate SVG data that is read from `STDIN`. In your case you can replace this with the call to `plantuml`.

Comment: That sounds very promising, especially as I can also avoid the tempoorary file. I will try this out. and let you know.

Comment: @Rainer I am very interested in the result. Would be cool if `plantuml` could be used in R-markdown documents.

Comment: OK - I just have pushed version 0.2.0. which uses svg as an intermediate format. It works partly with RStudio (the diagrams are in the knitted document), but I have no idea why they are not showing in the .Rmd document. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Out of interest: why did you recommend svg over eps? Any specific reasons?

Comment: @Rainer I have the impression that current development is happening for `grImports2`, and that is SVG only.

Comment: True - haven’t thought about that.

Comment: @Rainer However, since some things aren't working for you, it might be worth trying EPS via `grImports`, too.